# Security - is recommended to regenerate authorization codes for each request?

Tags: php, web-services, security, cookies

Suppose you have a cookie "code" containing a string of 80 characters, it is your access code for an application. It is recommended to regenerate this code every request to your application or is the same thing regenerate it when the first session of the page is created? I chose to use the first approach, but I noticed that while there is a long polling request is impossible to send a request (because I have to wait the request deadlines, to receive a new cookie). Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you edit your question and possibly add some examples? It might explain your question a bit better and you are more likely to get an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you regenerate your code every request, then someone refreshes too quickly, they will run into an HTTP race condition and lose their session. This creates a usability nightmare.

Regenerate your session IDs every time privileges are escalated (e.g. user logs in, or if users have a "change privilege" feature to switch between user mode and admin mode, etc). If you want a regular timeout, do something like this:

```
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['birth'])) $_SESSION['birth'] = time();
if( time() - $_SESSION['birth']) > 60 ) {
   // Every minute
   session_regenerate_id();
   $_SESSION['birth'] = time();
}
```

More important to security is using HTTPS (TLS 1.1+ if you can get away with it) with HSTS to prevent session fixation, specifying an entropy file (`/dev/urandom` for example), and optionally binding sessions to an IP address and user agent. (You can do this with similar application-layer logic to the snippet I posted above.)